# HTMX for messages from the backend in django

Tags: django, htmx

I wanted to use HTMX to show messages from django backend after a lot of trial and error I ended up with a working solution, that I want to leave behind for anyone looking for it - also, please feel free to post your suggestions. Unfortunately, besides a little [example](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-htmx/tree/main/example) from the htmx-django package, there is almost no tutorial material available. Be sure to check the example out, as it covers some basics specially for django users!

Comment: Since you solved the problem, please add an Answer below, containing the info you figured out, and select it as the correct answer. This will help others find this post when looking for similar information!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For HTMX we need a little element somewhere in the DOM that HTMX can work  (swap for example) with. Place for example a

```
<div id="msg">
    {% include "app/messages-partial.html" %} 
</div>
```

somewhere on your `index.html`. Now we want to use this element to fill it with content, if the need arises. Let's say we click a button, that communicates with a view and the answer gets posted. In django the response is created using `render`:

```
class TestView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "index.html"
    
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        class_code = """class='alert alert-dismissible fade show'"""
        msg_str = """testmessage"""
        msg_btn = """<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>x</button>"""
        msg = mark_safe(f"""<div {classcode}>{msg_str}{msg_btn}</div>""")
        return render(request, "app/messages-partial.html", {"msg": msg})
```

and a corresponding `path` in `urls.py`:

```
path("action/", views.TestView.as_view(), name = "test"),
```

I created a simple `messages-partial.html`:

```
{% if msg %}
    {{ msg }}
{% endif %}
```

So what I wanted is, when I triggered the the view, the `{{ msg }}` gets replaced (swapped) by HTMX to the content of the response. Therefore I implement the HTMX part somewhere else on the `index.html` as follows:

```
<div class="..."
     hx-get="/action"
     hx-swap="innerHTML"
     hx-target="#msg" >
         <button class="btn btn-primary">TEST</button>
</div>
```

The former `<div id="msg">...</div>` will swap with `{{ msg }}` (and I included the typical `django-messages` close button).

Thanks to the htmx discord channel where friendly people shared their knowledge with me.